# Better way for theming node_form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I've a module where I defined content type. Let's assume I have only `title` and `body` fields in it.

When node form renders it has standard `title (textfield)` and `body (textarea)`.

I want to wrap this two fields into `fieldset`.

This is how I achieve this, however I don't feel that it's the best way.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function hook_form($node, $form_state) {
  return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function hook_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'content_type_name_node_form') {
    $form['info'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Describe your content')
    );

    $form['info']['title'] = $form['title'];
    unset($form['title']);

    $form['info']['body'] = $form['body'];
    unset($form['body']);
  }
}
```

Any suggestions of how to make it better?

**UPDATE**

Another variant which I think of. It's pretty much the same, just a bit improved.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function hook_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'content_type_name_node_form') {
    $groups = array(
      'info' => array(
        'title' => t('Describe your content'),
        'fields' => array('title', 'body')
      )
    );

    foreach ($groups as $key => $group) {
      $form[$key] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => $group['title']
      );
      foreach ($group['fields'] as $field) {
        $form[$key][$field] = $form[$field];
        unset($form[$field]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd have to agree with David Fells -- I don't see an issue with how you've done it.

But just to offer you a non-programming way to set your title and body fields in a fieldset: you can check out the [Field Group module](http://drupal.org/project/field_group).

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All
>   fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap
>   their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers
>   like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div
>   wrappers

To be honest, it's likely overkill if all you want to do is create a fieldset for your title and body, but should you have other similar requirements for field grouping and theming, it might be useful to have UI to do it for you.

Comment: Fieldgroup is awesome. I agree it'd be overkill here but it would certainly do the job.

Comment: Really have to agree. Once you get large content types, being able to group those fields into vertical tabs and accordion groups is ftw.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it exactly as you should Vlad. That's the way the API is intended to be used, and there's really no other way to do it via code.

You can alter the layout using Panels as well, though I've not done it myself and can't explain the process, nor can I say with certainty that it will do exactly what you're doing here. Using a custom module is probably the most direct route.